# Why am I connected to 65.52.240.48?

Tags: ip-address

I notice my computer is connected to 65.52.240.48 using the firefox process. I looked it up it says the IP is in Redmond and "Microsoft Hosting" but I also get camtasia results.

I have camtasia installed but it's not opened. The connection has been opened for a long time. Why?

Comment: From a command prompt run `netstat -a -n -o` to find the process responsible for the connection and investigate from there.

Comment: @joeqwerty: its firefox, which puzzles me

Comment: You're connected to the internet?  Then you have an IP address.  If you go through a firewall it's likely 192.168..., but if directly connected it's whatever your internet provider uses.

Comment: 65.52.240.48 is redmond like I said. I live many timezones away. Also it only shows up with firefox (not chrome or IE). It doesn't show up on firefox on another computer on the network. I created a new profile with all extentions disabled (and addons don't exist on it). Still connects to it. IDK why firefox is connecting to it.

Answer (score 3):

These are [Windows Azure IaaS IP addresses](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/08/14/windows-azure-datacenter-ip-ranges.aspx#.UyPJzye9KK0). Anything can be hosted there, it likely isn't anything from Microsoft themselves.

Comment: This might be an unrelated question but doesn't 65.52.0.0/19 and 65.52.0.0/20 cover the same IPs?

Comment: @acidzombie24 That /19 is twice as big and yes, the first half of the /19 is the IPs in the /20.  It seems weird they would list them like that. There's a canonical subnetting question on ServerFault if you're interested in that topic.

Comment: If I understood correctly 65.52.240.48 falls under 65.52.224.0/19 which is Europe North yet iplookup says its in redmond which is not in europe.

Comment: You realize that Microsoft is headquartered in Redmond, WA right? And that they can announce IP addresses that they own from any Datacenter that they want, right?